# PHP script for a MySQL dump cron job

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I am trying to create a script that would run through a cron job, so it would dump the database on a regular basis. I also tried a couple of combinations with quotations and dots, but neither worked.

```
<?php
$date = date('Y-m-d-H:i:s');
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$database = 'databasename';
echo shell_exec("mysqldump -h $host -u $user -p$password $database > mysqlbackup$date.sql");
?>
```

Comment: use normal bash script, not PHP

Comment: Are you seeing any errors? Where exactly are you having problems?

Comment: Not knowing what errors you face, common things are: 1) the `mysqldump` executable not being found in `$PATH`, so use its full path.  2) password having characters that require quoting in the shell 3) specify a full path to the output file so you can find it.

Comment: @Lix - That's what you're supposed to do: "The password to use when connecting to the server. If you use the short option form (-p), you cannot have a space between the option and the password." http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Would that be the same for `-h $host -u $user`, or are the spaces ok, rather than the `-p` for the password?

Comment: @Fred-ii- its only the password parameter that shouldn't have a space before the password string

Comment: @andrew I just answered my own question lol thanks. I visited the link above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be a lot wiser to run the database dump directly as a cron job. I can see that you already have the command ready, so type `crontab -e` and enter something like to run it nightly at 03:30 AM:

```
30 03 * * * /usr/bin/mysqldump -u[username] -p[password] --all-databases --single-transaction > /home/USERNAME/backups/full_backup_`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S`.sql
```

And avoid writing your password in the command - instead, use [.my.cnf](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/password-security-user.html).

Comment: Ah, that was exactly what made me want to create it as a PHP script, because I wasn't aware that bash scripts can grab the date. I will give it a try, thank you very much.

Comment: it's not alway comfortable to avoid php in this case. 1. website connection settings are usually stored in `.php` file, not in config 2. you can manipulate previous dumps, say, delete some old ones